# Select a LI inside a NAV element using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS and I have been looking for a solution but I can't seem to make it working.

I have this simple nav:

```
<nav class="navbar-left">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="report.php">My usage report</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

How could I select and style the `li` inside the `nav` I have tried but it does not work:

```
.navbar-left li {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: your code working fine

Comment: That properly selects the element. If your styles aren't applying, there may be a [more specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) selector applying styles.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
nav > ul{
 background-color:red;
}
```

and try.

Comment: Please provide an explanation to your code and maybe a preview? It is very hard to understand something when you aren't told what it does.

Answer (score -2):

```css
.navbar-left ul {
  List-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.navbar-left ul li {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.navbar-left ul li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar-left">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="report.php">My usage report</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="report.php">My next report</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Use this code i hope its work..